# NANDroid backup/restore of CM11 encrypted device after wipe

Tags: backup, encryption, restore, twrp, cyanogenmod

is it possible to restore a NANDroid backup of a encrypted device running CyanogeMod 11 (KitKat 4.4.2) after performing "Format Data" in TWRP recovery (this function wipes the encrypted partitions)?

Here is scenario for such a case:

1. So, let's say I have an encrypted phone, which I back up
   periodically (with TWRP: boot, cache, data, efs, modem, system
   partitions)
2. Then, something gets messed up, so that I have to wipe
   all, reflash recovery, etc.
3. So I flash the working recovery with
   odin, boot to it, format data using TWRP, removing the encryption
   from the device
4. Now, I want to restore the NANDroid backup I've done
   before (when my system was encrypted)...

Will it work?????

Comment: I think encryption encrypt your sd card and /data and nandroid backup will backup your rom which is in system partition

Answer (score 0):

Yes

As far as I know, a NANDroid backup makes an Image of the entire device.
So, this can work because the entire file system is copied along with the file system. The device will still be encrypted after restoring.

I might be wrong because I've never done this. But if you encrypt a flash drive with bitlocker, copy the contents of it including the encryption, format the drive and copy it back; It will still contain the data if you decrypt it.